# fit_transform for the CustomEstimator is not working. Tried many ways but can anyone let me know what is going wrong in this code

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
class FillOutAverage(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        print("inside the filloutaverage")

    def fit(self, df,y=None):
        print("inside fillout fit method")
        return self


    def transform(self, df):
        print("got into fillout transform method")
        median_depth = df.groupby(['category'])['depth'].median().reset_index()
        median_depth.columns = ['category', 'MedianDepth']

        # Count the median value for height for each categories
        median_height = df.groupby(['category'])['height'].median().reset_index()
        median_height.columns = ['category', 'MedianHeight']

        # Count the median value for width for each categories
        median_width = df.groupby(['category'])['width'].median().reset_index()
        median_width.columns = ['category', 'MedianWidth']

        # Create new dataframe that contain the median for each dimensions, from each categories
        median_size = pd.merge(pd.merge(median_depth,median_height,on='category'),median_width,on='category')
        #print(median_size)

        df = pd.merge(df, median_size, on="category")
        df['depth'] = df['depth'].fillna(df["MedianDepth"])
        df["height"] = df["height"].fillna(df["MedianHeight"])
        df["width"] = df["width"].fillna(df["MedianWidth"])

        print("completed fillout out method")

        return df


class DataCompute(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        print("inside datacomputation")

    def fit(self,df=None, y=None):
        print("the length of the data columns",len(df.columns))
        return self

    def transform(self, df=None):
        print("Got into datacompute transform method")

        if df["old_price"] == "No old price" or str(df["old_price"])[-4:] == "pack":
            df["old_price"] = "0"
            df["old_price"] = df["old_price"].strip()
        if str(df["old_price"])[:2] == "SR":
            df["old_price"] = str(df["old_price"]).replace("SR ","").strip()
        if "," in str(df["old_price"]):
            df["old_price"] = str(df["old_price"]).replace(",","").strip()
        else:
            df["old_price"] = str(df["old_price"]).strip()
        
        df["old_price"] = np.where("0", df["old_price"], int(df["price"]))
        
        print(df["old_price"].unique())
        print("completed datacompute out method")

        return df

pipe1 = Pipeline([("fill_avg", FillOutAverage()), ("datacompute",DataCompute())])
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object')
num_cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude="object")
num_pipeline = Pipeline([("scaling", StandardScaler())])
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([("encoding", LabelEncoder())])
columns_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers= [("cat_cols",cat_pipeline, cat_cols),("num_cols",num_pipeline, num_cols)])
pipe2 = make_pipeline(pipe1, columns_transformer)
pipe2.fit_transform(df)
```

When executing this code, am getting error like truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Can someone help me in understanding what is going wrong in this code.
Not sure what is going wrong in this. I've tried of using the CustomTransformer using BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin.

I've created 2 customtransformers where the FillOutAverage() one is for filling the df[["width","height","length"]] with average values based on the category.

Comment: Please (always) provide the full error traceback.  Ideally, provide a minimal reproducible example: here, a toy dataset that demonstrates the error, and if possible remove some of the column transformer steps that aren't relevant to producing the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.